# Java Card Simulator memory specifications

Tags: java, simulator, javacard

I am currently working on deploying a development environment for a Java Card project .
After looking through a lot of documentation i cannot find a simple answer for how to allocate more or less RAM and ROM for the Java Card at startup.
`cref -help` also doesn't mention anything about it.
My default specifications are the ones below but i need them changed to match the physical card.
[image]

Comment: @CodingTil this question is about Java Card, which is Java for chip cards. The link you have posted is not relevant here.

Comment: Oh crap. Thought you meant something like Java Card Game Simulator. Sorry, my fault, didn't know about Java Card. I removed the comment